# How do I make a class assignable to primitives?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, variable-assignment, primitive

I was wondering if it's possible to make my

```
class Time
{
    public:
        Time();

        explicit
        Time(
            const double& d);

        Time&
        operator=(
            const Time& time);

        Time&
        operator=(
            const double& d);
};
```

assignable to the primitive double?

I'm using Time as an IV a lot and need to do a lot of scalar operations on it, so it needs to "mingle" with DV's which are usually ordinary doubles. Adding a second assignment operator did the trick the other way around.

A lot of operations still aren't possible with just this though. I've been writing operators outside of the Time class to allow for addition, substraction, multiplication and dividing between Time and double. But since assignment operators are not allowed outside a class, I'm unable to overcome this last error:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'double' to 'Time'    linearfit.cpp   67
```

Has anybody got any experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: What code gives you the error?

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is on a line like `Time t = 912.0;` Remove the word `explicit` from the constructor `Time(const double&)` and it will act as an implicit initialization from `double` to `Time`.

Comment: ah, sorry if I wasn't clear. Time t = 912.0 works perfectly fine. The other way around was what I was looking for. Thx!

Comment: @Rene: Your error message clearly shows you converting from `double` to `Time`, not the other way around.  Please post the _correct_ error message next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to write/override an operator. In this case the cast-operator.
Define a method

```
operator double() { return double_however_computed_from_your_time; };
```

Answer (score 3):

You should declare `operator double () const` to make `Time` convertible to `double`.
There is no way to overload the assignment operator for primitive types.

Comment: yes! thank you! I never knew this was possible. This was exactly what I was looking for. This works for primitives only? or for classes also? thx anyway!

Answer (score 3):

It appears likely that the error you've cited arises from having marked your `Time(const double &d)` as `explicit`. Remove the explicit, and implicit conversion from `double` to `Time` should work (with the proviso that this may also let it happen at times you'd rather it didn't). I'd probably also pass the double by value rather than const reference.

Converting from Time to double would be accomplished with:

```
class Time { 
// ...
     operator double() const;
};
```